# Timer CTC Set and Clear modes -- How to un-Clear and un-Set?

Tags: pwm, timers

Nick Gammon's cheatsheet for the Ardunino UNO's ATmega328P (below) shows some hints on the Clear Timer on Compare (CTC) modes of AVR chips.  Most of the examples for CTC mode I find use the COMxxx registers of 01 = toggle to control the OCxx pin, which would give a 50% duty cycle at 1/2 the frequency of the timer clearing.

My question is about using the non-toggling COMxxx modes of Clear and Set, which don't seem to provide an automatic way to reset into the opposite state, as in the PWM modes.

For example:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

   // Timer 1 CTC mode Clearing OC1B at 0.25Hz using OCR1A to set frequency
   // Output on OC1B  
   // Clear at OCR1B
   // WGM =15 0b0100 

   DDRB |= bit(DDB5)| bit(DDB6);  // Teensy2.0 atmega32u OC1A and OC1B outputs
  // DDRB |= bit(DDB1)| bit(DDB2);  // atmega168/UNO OC1A and OC1B (Tested by OP/Luis)
   TCCR1A =  bit(COM1A0) | bit(COM1B1)  ; // Toggle OC1A, Clear on OC1B    
   TCCR1B =  bit(WGM12)  | bit(CS12);  // Set /1 prescaler
   TCCR1C = 0;  // Note that it is good to initialize the timer
                // into a known mode before trying to set interesting TOPs 
   OCR1A  = 62500U ;    // Set TOP count to 16000000/(PreScaler *Ftimer)
   OCR1B  = OCR1A/2;    //  ~50% duty cycle
   TCCR1A =  bit(COM1A0) | bit(COM1B1)  ; // Toggle OC1A, Clear on OC1B    
   TCCR1B =  bit(WGM12)  | bit(CS12) | bit(CS10);  // Set /1024 prescaler
   TCNT1 = 0 ;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //OCR1B = 62500U/4-1; // 25% duty cycle. 
}
```

If I try the above code, I get a 0.125Hz ( 8s period signal) on PB5 and a constant low on PB6.

What is the way to set OC1B high to be cleared by the timer match?  And similarly, vice versa: clearing OC1B to be set by the timer match?

Is there a direct way or do you fiddle with COM1Bx, trigger FOC1B, and then fiddle COM1B back?

[image]

This code uses the TCCR1C:FOC1B register to set the bit by messing with the TCCR1A:COM1Bx bits, but it seems awkward:

```cpp
void setup() {
   // Timer 1 CTC mode Clearing OC1B at 0.25Hz using OCR1A to set frequency
   // Output on OC1B  
   // Clear at OCR1B
   // WGM =15 0b0100 

   DDRB |= bit(DDB5)| bit(DDB6);  // Teensy2.0 atmega32u OC1A and OC1B outputs
  // DDRB |= bit(DDB1)| bit(DDB2);  // atmega168/UNO OC1A and OC1B (Tested by OP/Luis)
   TCCR1A =  bit(COM1A0) | bit(COM1B1)  ; // Toggle OC1A, Clear on OC1B    
   TCCR1B =  bit(WGM12)  | bit(CS12);  // Set /1 prescaler
   TCCR1C = 0;  // Note that it is good to initialize the timer
                // into a known mode before trying to set interesting TOPs 
   OCR1A  = 62500U ;    // Set TOP count to 16000000/(PreScaler *Ftimer)
   OCR1B  = OCR1A/2;    //  ~50% duty cycle
   TCCR1A =  bit(COM1A0) | bit(COM1B1)  ; // Toggle OC1A, Clear on OC1B    
   TCCR1B =  bit(WGM12)  | bit(CS12) | bit(CS10);  // Set /1024 prescaler
   TCNT1 = 0 ;
}

void loop() {
  int saveCOM;
  Serial.println(TCCR1A,BIN);
  delay(7000); // 7 seconds
  saveCOM = TCCR1A; 
  TCCR1A |= bit(COM1B1) | bit(COM1B0) ; // config for set OC1B
  TCCR1C = bit(FOC1B); // force a compare to set bit
  TCCR1A = saveCOM ; // restore mode
}
```

This code has the 0.125Hz on OC1A, and a semi-random series of 1-4 second long pulses on OC1B.

I was interested in playing with the CTC modes for doing long cycle/low frequency PWM.  With the normal PWMs you could range from a 1-bit 50% PWM at 8MHz to a 16 bit PWM at a frequency of 0.119Hz (8.388s)  With the CTC modes, if you could manage the sets and clears in an TIMERx_OVF_vect with a couple 16 bit registers, you could extend it to 32 bits of PWM resolution with a period up to 152 hours.

Comment: If you don't set the WGM mode before you set the TOP/OCR1A/ICR1, it could be truncated to 8 (, 9, or 10?) bits from the Arduino default WGM=5=0b0101 modes.

Comment: You can set the output using `digitalWrite(10, HIGH)`. On compare match it's cleared. If it was already cleared, nothing happens. This would be useful to create a **single** pulse of a precise length.

Comment: @Gerben Maybe it's my Teensy 2.0, but putting digitalWrite(PIN_B6,HIGH) or digitalWrite(15, HIGH) seems to stay high forever after the CTC config, or be cleared immediately if before the CTC setup. Checking TCCRA1, it seems that digitalWrite(PIN_B6,HIGH) unsets COM1B1 and COM1B0.

Comment: Sorry, stupid me. The digitalWrite implementation will disable PWM. Instead do something like `PORTB |= _BV(PB2)`.

Comment: @Gerben.  Stiil nope.  it seems that the PORTB bit value is inhibited/overriden by the OC1B state.  "If one or both of the COMnB1:0 bits are written to one, the OCnB output overrides the normal port func- tionality of the I/O pin it is connected to. If one or both of the COMnC1:0 bits are written to one, the OCnC output overrides the normal port functionality of the I/O pin it is connected to." in the TCCR1A section of my datasheet.  If I toggle COM1Bxx on and off with an underlying high PORTB, it toggles the voltage off and on at the pin.

Comment: `Teensy2.0 atmega32u` - my cheat sheet was for the Atmega328P. Things are likely to be a bit different.

Comment: It is a bit different, e.g., the atmega32u has an OC1C, and they are on different bits, but the basic functionality appears to be much the same.

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30507/timer2-clear-oc2b-on-compare-match-not-working-as-expected-in-ctc-mode/30529#30529 is related